# How to get logged in business account id in acumatica portal?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to filter the catalog item based on logged in customer business account. How do i get the logged in customer business account value in acumatica portal?

Regards,
R.Muralidharan

Comment: I have used the following statement to get the logged in user business account

                Guid id = PXAccess.GetUserID();
                Contact contact = PXSelect<Contact, Where<Contact.userID, Equal<Required<Contact.userID>>>>.Select(Base, id);

is there any better option available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found out, `PXAccess.GetUserID()` allows you to get this information, but you can also use the AccessInfo DAC in BQL queries:

```
Current<AccessInfo.userID>
Current<AccessInfo.userName>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used Base.currentCustomer.BAccountID and it works fine